# How to index feed in Google Search Appliance?

Tags: django, google-search, google-search-appliance

i have my atom (list of continent as xml) at this url `.../continent/search?view=atom` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
    <title>List of all continents</title>
    <opensearch:totalResults>{{ continents_length }}</opensearch:totalResults>
    <opensearch:startIndex>{{ continents.start_index }}</opensearch:startIndex>
    <opensearch:itemsPerPage>{{ count }}</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
    <opensearch:Query continent="request" searchTerms="" startPage="{{ continents.start_index }}" />
    <author><name>My_site</name></author>
    <id>urn:domain-id:mysite.com:continent</id>

    <link rel="self" href="{{ url }}" />
    {% for continent in continents %}
    <entry>
        <span class="continent_id">{{ continent.continent_id }}</span>
        <span class="continent_name">{{ continent.continent_name }}</span>
        <span class="list_countries">{{ continent.list_countries }}</span>
    </entry>
    {% endfor %}
</feed>
```

When i want to PUT and index my feed in gsa-interface i have used this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <title>continent</title>
    <id>urn:domain-id:mysite.com:continent</id>
    <author>
        <name>admin user</name>
    </author>
    <link rel="self" href=".../feed/continent"/>
    <content type="xhtml">
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <span id="refresh-each">15 12,14,18 * * *</span>
            <span id="gsa-datasource">continent</span>
            <span id="gsa-feedtype">full</span>
            <span id="url">...continent/search?view=atom</span>
            <span id="opensearch-pattern">&amp;count=100&amp;startPage=%STARTPAGE%</span>
            <ul class="connection">
                <li id="userid">user</li>
                <li id="password">pass</li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="metadata">
                <li id="continent_id">atom:entry/xhtml:span[@class='continent_id']</li>
                <li id="continent_name">atom:entry/xhtml:span[@class='continent_name']</li>
                <li id="list_countries">atom:entry/xhtml:span[@class='list_countries']</li>
            </ul>
            <div id="xsl-content">
                <![CDATA[
                    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                        xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
                        xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                        exclude-result-prefixes="atom xhtml">

                        <xsl:template name="FormatDescription">
                            <xsl:param name="name"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
                        </xsl:template>

                        <xsl:template match="atom:entry">
                            <html>
                                <body>
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="atom:entry/xhtml:span" />
                                </body>
                            </html>
                        </xsl:template>
                        <xsl:template match="atom:entry/xhtml:span">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                        </xsl:template>

                    </xsl:stylesheet>
                ]]>
            </div>
        </div>
    </content>
</entry>
```

But when i check the flux of transfered files it return 0 file with error:

```
ProcessNode: Missing required attribute url. skipping element., skipping record
```

For the second indexation and the tird one, there is no error, and neither no file !

```
200 OK Feed continent has been pushed successfully to the Google Search Appliance.
```

Any suggestion/recommandation ?

Comment: Hi, I saw your questions researching my own GSA feed issue today.  Are you sure you can just inject ATOM feeds into the GSA without transforming them first, perhaps via XSLT?  Possibly they do allow that, I'm not sure, but have you seen this page about the gsa feed protocol?  https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/64/feedsguide

Answer (score 2):

Following up on this, the word "feed" is confusing here.  A GSA content feed is not like any RSS or Atom feeds.  Here's a simplified example (from the documentation):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE gsafeed PUBLIC "-//Google//DTD GSA Feeds//EN" "">
<gsafeed>
   <header>
     <datasource>hello</datasource>
     <feedtype>incremental</feedtype>
   </header>
  <record url="http://www.corp.enterprise.com/hello02" mimetype="text/plain">
    <content>UPDATED - This is hello02</content>
  </record>
</group>
</gsafeed>
```

As you can see, that's a very specific XML format, not shared with web site update feed formats.  The documentation for this is good: http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/70/gsa_doc_set/feedsguide/feedsguide.html

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [feed documentation](https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/2765939?hl=en&ref_topic=2707841)

You need to pass the GSA a feed XML file, not an atom feed.